# Double dual of free $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, duality

For an abelian group $A$, put $DA=\text{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z})$ and $D_{(p)}A=\text{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})$.  It is a theorem of Specker that when $A$ is free abelian of countable rank, the natural map $A\to D^2(A)$ is an isomorphism.  The proof uses the ordering of $\mathbb{Z}$ in an essential way: at a key step we have integers $n,m$ with $|n|<m$ and $n=0\pmod{m}$ and we conclude that $n=0$.

Is it also true that when $A$ is a free module of countable rank over $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, the natural map $A\to D_{(p)}^2(A)$ is an isomorphism?  As the order-theoretic properties of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ are worse than those of $\mathbb{Z}$, it does not seem possible to adapt Specker's argument in any obvious way.

Comment: I *think* that my favourite proof of Specker’s theorem also works here, but I might well be missing something. I’ll be back when I’ve had time to think it through carefully.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is at least one proof of Specker's theorem that can be adapted in an obvious way. I believe that the first half of this proof is due to Sąsiada, and the second half to Łoś.

Let $A$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ module of countable rank, and $B=D_{(p)}A$
its dual, whose elements I will think of as sequences of elements of
$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. Let $e_{n}\in B$ be the sequence with $n$th term equal to
$1$ and all other terms zero.

It is easy to see that to prove that the natural map $A\to D^{2}_{(p)}A$ is an
isomorphism, it is enough to prove the following two facts about elements
$\varphi:B\to\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ of $D_{(p)}B$.

**Proposition 1.** $\varphi(e_{n})=0$ for all but finitely many $n$.

*Proof.* Suppose not. By ignoring those $n$ for which $\varphi(e_{n})=0$, we can
assume, for simplicity, that $\varphi(e_{n})\neq0$ for all $n$.

Construct a sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in B$ by inductively choosing
$x_{n}$ to be nonzero but divisible by a higher power of $p$ than
$\varphi(x_{n-1}e_{n-1})$.

Now consider all sequences whose $n$th term is either $x_{n}$ or $0$. There are
uncountably many of these, but $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is countable, so two of these
sequences must be sent to the same place by $\varphi$. Taking the difference, we
get a nonzero sequence $(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ker(\varphi)$ with $y_{n}$
equal to $0$ or to $\pm x_{n}$. Choosing $m$ minimal such that $y_{m}\neq0$ we
have
$$0=\varphi((y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}})=
\varphi(y_{m}e_{m})+\varphi((y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}-y_{m}e_{m}),$$ but
$(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}-y_{m}e_{m}$, and hence $\varphi((y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}-y_{m}e_{m})$, is divisible by a higher power of
$p$ than $\varphi(y_{m}e_{m})$. $\;\blacksquare$

**Proposition 2.** $\varphi$ is determined by the values of $\varphi(e_{n})$.

*Proof.* If not, there is some nonzero $\varphi\in D_{(p)}B$ with
$\varphi(e_{n})=0$ for all $n$.

Choose a sequence $(a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\not\in\ker(\varphi)$, and define a
homomorphism $\theta:B\to B$
by
$$\theta((b_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}})=((b_{0}+b_{1}+\cdots+b_{n})a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.$$

For each $m$, $\theta(e_{m})$ differs from $(a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in only
finitely many terms, so
$\varphi\theta(e_{m})=\varphi((a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}})\neq0$ for all $n$,
contradicting Proposition 1 for $\varphi\theta$. $\;\blacksquare$

Comment: I think that if $R$ is any proper subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ then we can choose a prime $p$ that is not invertible in $R$ and use the above argument to show that $\chi\colon F\to\text{Hom}(\text{Hom}(F,R),R)$ is an isomorphism whenever $F$ is free and countable.   Essentially the same argument shows that $\chi$ is a split monomorphism whenever $F$ is free, even if it is uncountable.  If I understand correctly, there is some story relating the cokernel to ultrafilters and measurable cardinals.

Answer (score 7):

[E. E. Enochs, “A note on reflexive modules”, *Pacific J. Math.* **14** (1964), 879–881](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-14/issue-3/A-note-on-reflexive-modules/pjm/1103033984.full?tab=ArticleLink) shows that, over a discrete valuation ring $R$, the free module with denumerable base is reflexive (meaning that the canonical linear map to its bidual is an isomorphism) iff the base ring $R$ is *not* complete.  In particular, this answers your question affirmatively by applying to $R = \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ (which is not complete).