# Rings over which free modules of a certain rank are reflexive (satisfy Specker's theorem)

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, modules, duality

Following [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453688/double-dual-of-free-mathbbz-p-modules) about the case of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, I've got to ask what is known more generally about rings and dimensions for which Specker's theorem holds.  Let me make the following definitions:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ a set (of which only the cardinality $|I|$ will matter).  Denote as usual by $R^{(I)}$ and $R^I$ the $R$-modules of functions $I\to R$ with finite support, resp. all functions $I\to R$: the former is the free $R$-module with basis $e_i$ where $e_i$ is the function with value $1$ at $i$ and $0$ elsewhere, and the latter is identified with its dual $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom_R(R^{(I)},R)$ as usual (viꝫ., by identifying $(c_i)_ {i\in I} \in R^I$ with $R^{(I)} \to R,\; (x_i)_ {i\in I} \mapsto \sum_ {i\in I} c_i x_i$).

Just to fix notations: let $\iota \colon R^{(I)} \to R^I$ be the obvious inclusion (and let's agree to write $e_i$ for $\iota(e_i)$).  Let $\iota^* \colon \Hom_R(R^I,R) \to R^I$ be its transpose (taking a linear form $\lambda$ on $R^I$ to the function $(\lambda(e_i))_ {i\in I} \in R^I$).  And let $\Phi \colon R^{(I)} \to \Hom_R(R^I,R)$ be the canonical biduality map (taking $(x_i)_ {i\in I} \in R^{(I)}$ to $R^I \to R,\; (v_i)_ {i\in I} \mapsto \sum_ {i\in I} v_i x_i$).  Note the obvious fact that $\iota = \iota^* \circ \Phi$ (in particular, $\Phi$ is injective and the imega of $\iota^*$ contains that of $\iota$, that is, $R^{(I)}$).

**Definition:** Say that $R$ is $|I|$-**Speckerian** (my terminology), or simply Speckerian for $|I|=\aleph_0$, when the following equivalent statements are satisfied:

1. $R^{(I)}$ is reflexive, i.e., $\Phi$ is bijective (equivalently, surjective).
2. **(a)** $\iota^*$ is injective, *and* **(b)** its image is included in that of $\iota$ (that is, $R^{(I)}$; of course, it is then equal).

(Their equivalence is a fairly straightforward consequence of $\iota = \iota^* \circ \Phi$.)

Say that $R$ is $|I|$-**prespeckerian** (again my terminology, sorry if it's abominable) when (2)(a) is satisfied, i.o.w. any linear form $\lambda$ on $R^I$ such that vanishes on all the $e_i$ is in fact zero, and $|I|$-**postspeckerian** when (2)(b) is satisfied, i.o.w., for any linear form $\lambda$ on $R^I$ all but finitely many of the $\lambda(e_i)$ are zero.

**A few known (or easy) facts:**

- A field is not $\kappa$-Speckerian for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, in fact, it is neither $\kappa$-prespeckerian nor $\kappa$-postspeckerian.  Indeed, if $k$ is a field, we can always find a linear form $\lambda$ on $k^I$ that vanishes on $k^{(I)}$ but not elsewhere, violating (2)(a), and we can also find one which takes arbitrarily prescribed values on the linearly independent $e_i$, showing that the image of $\iota^*$ is all of $R^I$, violating (2)(b).
- A Noetherian¹ domain $R$ having a prime element $\pi$ such that the localization $A_{(\pi)}$ at the prime ideal generated by $\pi$ is **not** complete, is Speckerian: [E. E. Enochs, “A note on reflexive modules”, *Pacific J. Math.* **14** (1964), 879–881](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-14/issue-3/A-note-on-reflexive-modules/pjm/1103033984.full), corollary to theorem 1.  In particular, $\mathbb{Z}$ is Speckerian (recall that this means “$\aleph_0$-Speckerian”): this is Specker's theorem, explaining my choice of terminology.
- It turns out that, when $|I|=\aleph_0$, then (2)(b)⇒(2)(a) (“postspeckerian implies Speckerian”), as shown in [Jeremy Rickard's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453688/double-dual-of-free-mathbbz-p-modules/453753#453753) to the aforementioned question, who attributes it to Łos, and which I'm merely rephrasing. We can take $I=\mathbb{N}$.  Assume $\iota^* (\lambda)=0$ for some $\lambda \in \Hom_R(R^ {\mathbb{N}}, R)$, and let $u = (u_n)_ {n\in\mathbb{N}} \in R^ {\mathbb{N}}$.  Define $\theta\colon R^{\mathbb{N}} \to R^ {\mathbb{N}}$ by
  $$
  \theta((x_n)_ {n\in\mathbb{N}}) = ((u_0+\cdots+u_n)\, x_n)_ {n\in\mathbb{N}}
  $$
  In particular, $\theta(e_m)$ coincides with $u$ from rank $m$ onward, i.e., differs from $u$ by a linear combination of $e_0,\ldots,e_ {m-1}$, but $\lambda(e_i) = 0$ by assumption, so that $\lambda(\theta(e_m)) = \lambda(u)$, in other words, $\iota^* (\lambda\circ \theta)$ is the *constant* sequence with value $\lambda(u)$; but now our hypothesis (2)(b) implies that $\lambda(u)=0$.  Since $u$ was arbitrary, we get $\lambda=0$ so $\iota^*$ is injective. ∎
- If $\kappa\leq\lambda$, then $\lambda$-Speckerian implies $\kappa$-Speckerian, and the same holds for the corresponding pre- and postspeckerian conditions separately.  Indeed, if $I\subseteq J$ (with $|I|=\kappa$ and $|J|=\lambda$), and if $\newcommand{\res}{\operatorname{res}}\res:R^J\to R^I$ and $\newcommand{ext}{\operatorname{ext}}\ext:R^I\to R^J$ denote restriction and extension by zero respectively, then for $\lambda \in \Hom_R(R^I,R)$ we have $\iota_J^* (\lambda\circ\res) = \ext(\iota_I^* (\lambda))$ (by straightforwardly computing their value at $e_i$).
- If $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal, and $|R| < \kappa$, then $R$ is *not* $\kappa$-Speckerian, or indeed $\kappa$-prespeckerian.  Indeed, if $\mathscr{U}$ is a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $I$ with $|I| = \kappa$, then $\lim_{\mathscr{U}} \colon R^I \to R$ is $R$-linear (it takes values in $R$ because $|R|<\kappa$ ensures that every element of $R^I$ is $\mathscr{U}$-almost-everywhere equal to some constant) and vanishes on the $e_i$, so it is in the kernel of $\iota^*$.

I don't know anything else about the notion.  Hence:

**General question:** Are there any notable results in the literature pertaining to these notions (obviously, not under the names I just made up)?

**Specfic questions:**

- Is $\mathbb{Z}$ (or, more generally, any ring satisfying the hypotheses of Enochs's aforementioned result) $\kappa$-speckerian for any $\kappa$ less than the first measurable cardinal if it exists (or any $\kappa$ otherwise)?
- Does there exist a ring that is ($\aleph_0$-)Speckerian but not $\aleph_1$-Speckerian?
- Does there exist a ring that is prespeckerian but not Speckerian?
- Does there exist a ring that is $\kappa$-postspeckerian but not $\kappa$-Speckerian (for some $\kappa$, necessarily $>\aleph_0$ by what has been said)?

**Footnote:**

1. Enochs does not write “Noetherian” in the statement, but it seems to me it [cannot be omitted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155621/condition-for-a-local-ring-whose-maximal-ideal-is-principal-to-be-noetherian) to conclude that $A_{(\pi)}$ is a discrete valuation ring.  Maybe I missed something or I'm confused.